# 下記コードの実行結果について

Tags: java

質問：UseBank.javaの6行目から１０行目がどのような動きになっているかを詳しく教えてください。

#### Bank.java

```
 1:public class Bank{
 2:  private int money;
 3:  public void setMoney(int money) {
 4:    this.money = money;      //引く数をフィールドに代入
 5:  }
 6:  public int getMoney() {
 7:     return money;
 8:  }
 9:}
```

#### UseBank.java

```
 1: pubulic class UseBank {
 2:   public static void main(Steing[] args) {
 3:    //クラス　Bankのインスタンス化
 4:      Bank bank = new Bank();
 5:      int mny = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
 6:      bank.setMoney(mny);
 7:      System.out.println("振込額 : " + mny);
 8:    //bank.money = 0;    //エラーが発生します
 9:      int nowMoney = bank.getMoney();
10:     System.out.println("現在の所持金 : " + nowmoney;
11:   }
12: }
```

#### 実行結果

```
 >java Usebank 10000 

振込額　: 10000
現在の所持金 : 10000
```

Answer (score 2):

わかりやすいように図にしてみました。まずは3行目の状態です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

まだmainを実行したばかりなので何もないですね。（※ 正確には、`args`という変数に、プログラムを実行したときのパラメータのデータが入っていますが、図では省略しています。）

では次に4行目、ここでbankを作っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑ bank変数の中に、Bankクラスが初期化されました。ちなみに青色の部分は、privateなので直接は見たり触ったりできません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑ 5行目で、`args[0]`に入った `"10000"` という文字列を、`mny`という変数に`10000`という数値に変換して入れています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑ 7行目は、`setMoney`メソッドを通じて、`bank`の`money`変数に`10000`をセットしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

↑ 最後に9行目で、`getMoney`メソッドを通じて、`bank`の`money`変数の値を、`nowMoney`変数にコピーしています。

なお、説明を省いた `System.out.println` は、画面に結果を表示するメソッドですね。

Comment: this.money = money;   これがなぜmnyの10000をmoneyに代入することになるのでしょうか？

Comment: serMoney(mny) が呼ばれたとき、mnyはsetMoneyメソッドの第一引数にセットされます。このとき、紛らわしいのですが、第一引数の名前が money で、 this.money はインスタンス変数のmoneyを指しますから、インスタンス変数に値をセットすることになります。　https://imgur.com/gallery/jQT8IXQ この辺がとても初心者には紛らわしいので、引数の名前をインスタンス変数と同じ名前にすることは避けて、`_money`などを引数名としてリネームするとよりわかりやすいです。

Answer (score 1):

4行目で作成したBankクラスのインスタンスであるbankのmoneyプロパティに，5行目でparseしたmnyをセット（わかりやすく言うと代入みたいな）をしている．

```
bank.setMoney(mny);
```

5行目のmnyを表示．

```
System.out.println("振込額 : " + mny);
```

bankインスタンスのmoneyプロパティにはprivate修飾子がついているため直接アクセスは不可能．

```
//bank.money = 0;    //エラーが発生します
```

getterを介してbankインスタンスのmoneyを取得して変数nowMoneyを初期化．

```
int nowMoney = bank.getMoney();
```

nowMoneyを表示．

```
System.out.println("現在の所持金 : " + nowmoney);
```